# jQuery-Masonry Items Dont Rearrange on Hiding a Div/Element

Tags: jquery-masonry

Im trying to implement a filter on the **jQuery-masonry.**
But the problem is if i hide a middle element, others dont rearrange.
This leaves lots of **gutters** in between.
Tried the **.masonry('reload');**

Caan anyone please help.

Comment: Sure, but without making an effort to show a jsfiddle of the issue or sharing your website's online sandbox, it will be difficult to guess at where you went wrong. For filtering, you use Isotope not Masonry. It's developed by the same autor.

Answer (score -2):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/126). Workaround: use *:visible* on your selector.

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.mybrick:visible'
});
```

Comment: The issue is now closed (since v3). I am guessing this is not a problem anymore in v3.

Comment: Still a problem for me. This fixed it. EDIT.. no it didn't 'xxx:visible is not a valid selector'