# jQuery / Desandro masonry does not rearrange after filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I've implemented a filter on my [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) but I'm having problem re-arranging my elements after I've hidden some of the elements (images).

I've tried [zesc solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530966/jquery-masonry-items-dont-rearrange-on-hiding-a-div-element), but that's not working. I've also tried appending only visible elements to my container, but that's not helping either.

How can I get masonry to re-arrange after I filter my elements?

I've [created a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJgBY/4/).

PS. I've tried the plugin `Isotope`, but there is a bug making some images not visible in IE.

Comment: I've try to test this solution but don't have much time, and can't figure it to work just now, but you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131080/jquery-masonryhide-element-method-with-a-jquery-element take a look

Comment: There is a bug issue on this as well, but he says it should be fixed now: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/126 - but I'm not so sure.

Comment: I get it working removing the elements, but isn't the solution. So you can temporary use this, remove from the div you want to sort and put it on other hide div. And manipulate the elements, its a hard work but its what we have now.

Comment: @Guerra do you know how I can re-instantiate Masonry on remaining elements?

Comment: Just call   $container.masonry();  again.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. Can you make it work in my Fiddle, I'll be a very happy man :-)

Comment: In this new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fJgBY/4/ I've also tried using `.layout()`, but still it's not working.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this on the fiddle, but fiddle its terrible to develop on it. Will get it on my local workbeach and will try to solve. On documentation of masonry have many things can solve it i thing

Comment: Let me know if you are successfull. Even the developer of Masonry isn't very hopefull :) https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/126

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#items_container").masonry({
        itemSelector: curr_filter,
        columnWidth: curr_filter,
        gutter: 20, 
        columns: 3,
        transitionDuration: '1.5s'
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it with the new version of Masonry.